# Count NULL values by column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, null

I'm trying to sum the number of NULL values in my dataframe in R.  I can easily do so with NA values using the code below:

```
colSums(is.na(df))
```

but when I attempt to do this with is.null I get back the following error:

Error in colSums(is.null(df)) :
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

I believe the solution is to change the dataframe into another form to do this - but I don't know how and internet searches have proven fruitless (and often conflate NAs and NULLs)

Comment: `is.na()` returns a logical matrix with the same dimensions as the data frame, whereas `is.null()` returns a single TRUE/FALSE value. It would help to see some or all of the data `df` (including the NULL values) using _e.g._ `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df))`. NULL may not mean what you think it means _e.g._ it may be stored as type character.

Answer (score 1):

NULL values in data frames are actually empty lists. You have to check whether their length is 0. Either in tidyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tribble(~a, ~b,
             "a", NULL,
             NULL, "y",
             "b", "z")
d
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# a         b        
# <list>    <list>   
# 1 <chr [1]> <NULL>   
# 2 <NULL>    <chr [1]>
sum(map_dbl(d, ~length(~.x) > 0))
# [1] 2

or Base R:

d <- data.frame(a = I(list("a", NULL, "b")),
                b = I(list(NULL, "y", "z")))
d
# a b
# 1 a  
# 2   y
# 3 b z
sum(apply(d, 2, function(a) sum(vapply(a, function(b) length(b) == 0L, numeric(1)))))
#[1] 2
```